# How do I make a div's width 100% to the parent div?

Tags: html, css

In the following piece of code, the pink div is overflowing. How do I make the width 100% inside the parent div?

Here's a JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8q8n6bt5/

```
#mobilefooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #06C;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 99;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.foxmobile {
    width: 42px;
    height: 60px;
    background:#2CDB46;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.footercontext {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #F36;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;


}
.footercontext p {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: it can't be 100% because there is a sibling with 42px width.. your div will have to be (100% - 64px) you can use the calc() function but it doesn't have much support - you can try a relative percentage like 95% for red box and 5% for green box

Comment: I've requested an edit to your post. Here, in SO, questions must be concise and, therefore, avoid using certain unnecessary expressions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you could also try `display:table` and `display:table-cell`: https://jsfiddle.net/g8jdp3ey/. It's easier to layout your UI in this case.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I understand the problem much more clearly now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind is `margin-left: 45px;` of .footercontext. Just add this code line: `width: calc(100% - 45px);` so it will make your `.footercontext` 100% by deducting 45px of margin.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q8n6bt5/4/)

```
.footercontext {
    width: calc(100% - 45px); /* CHANGED */
    height: 60px;
    background: #F36;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    }
```

```css
body{ margin:0px;}
#mobilefooter {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background: #06C;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline;
 z-index: 99;
 bottom: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.foxmobile {
 width: 42px;
 height: 60px;
 background:#2CDB46;
 margin-top: 5px;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}

.footercontext {
 width: calc(100% - 45px);
 height: 60px;
 background: #F36;
 color: #FFF;
 margin-left: 45px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 display: block;
 
 
}
.footercontext p {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobilefooter">
 <div class="foxmobile"></div>
    <div class="footercontext">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Note : Also added `body{margin:0px;}` to ignore body margin's.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove width:100% from `.footercontext`. It will automatically expand to fit the parent.

```css
#mobilefooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #06C;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.foxmobile {
  width: 42px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #2CDB46;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
.footercontext {
  height: 60px;
  background: #F36;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.footercontext p {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobilefooter">
  <div class="foxmobile"></div>
  <div class="footercontext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `width: auto` on the `.footercontext` element.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8q8n6bt5/2/)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#mobilefooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #06C;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  z-index: 99;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.foxmobile {
  width: 42px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #2CDB46;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
.footercontext {
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  background: #F36;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.footercontext p {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobilefooter">
  <div class="foxmobile"></div>
  <div class="footercontext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```